# Circuit breaker exception elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

```
{
  'error': {
    'type': 'circuit_breaking_exception',
    'reason': '[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [123848638/118.1mb], which is larger than the limit of [123273216/117.5mb], real usage: [120182112/114.6mb], new bytes reserved: [3666526/3.4mb]',
    'bytes_wanted': 123848638,
    'bytes_limit': 123273216,
    'durability': 'TRANSIENT'
  },
  'status': 429
}
```

I am trying to understand the above circuit breaker error.

- [123273216/117.5mb] - parent circuit breaker limit (95%).
- new bytes reserved [3666526/3.4mb] - this means the new request memory needs
- [123848638/118.1mb] - current heap + new bytes reserved
- real usage: [120182112/114.6mb] - current heap status

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, basically:

1. the current heap usage is 120,182,112
2. the new bytes needed to carry out the request is 3,666,526
3. the bytes wanted from memory would thus be 1 + 2 = 123,848,638
4. the total heap is 129,761,280
5. the maximum reservable heap memory for the parent circuit breaker is [95% of total heap](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html#parent-circuit-breaker) = 123,273,216

Since 3 (bytes wanted) > 5 (circuit breaker limit), the **circuit breaker trips**

Comment: "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "circuit_breaking_exception",
                "reason": "[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be   [1009752570/962.9mb], which is larger than the limit of [1003493785/957mb], real usage: [1009743920/962.9mb], new bytes reserved: [8650/8.4kb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=0/0b, in_flight_requests=8650/8.4kb, accounting=6431796/6.1mb]",
                "bytes_wanted": 1009752570,
                "bytes_limit": 1003493785,
                "durability": "PERMANENT"
            }
        ],
}

Comment: Thanks but I am applying the same logic to the above error I faced while working on a project. 
For calculating the bytes wanted from memory do we need to add new bytes reserved+ usages?

Comment: 1009743920 (real usage) + 8650 (new bytes reserved) = 1009752570 (bytes_wanted) > 1003493785 (bytes_limit = 95% of heap)